# Is there a Button such as UIButton in COCOS2D?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I try to search a button such as UIButton in cocos2d..

UIButton can press several buttons at same time.

but CCmenuitem can't..

Is there anyclass in cocos2d such as uibutton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend CCMenu to support multitouch. It was designed to use targeted touches, that is, single touch interactions. With a little elbow grease, it wouldn't be difficult at all to extend it to support multitouch.

Answer (score 0):

CCMenuItems are used instead of UIButton in cocos2d. A single CCMenuItem inside your CCMenu can exactly work like the UIButton.

You can create that in the following way.

```
  //inside your .m file

-(id) init
{
  if( (self=[super init] )) {


    CCMenuItem *yourMenuItem = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"normalImage.png" selectedImage:@"selectedImage.png" target:self selector:@selector(menuItemPressed:)];
    yourMenuItem.position = ccp(60, 60);
    CCMenu *yourMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:yourMenuItem, nil];
    yourMenu.position = CGPointZero;
    [self addChild:yourMenu];
  }
}
```

There's a good article by Ray Wenderlich on this [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/414/how-to-create-buttons-in-cocos2d-simple-radio-and-toggle).

However, if your main requirement is to add a UIButton only then [this](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/4481) discussion might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would also take a look at [SneakyInput](http://www.qcmat.com/sneakyinput-joystick-dpad-and-buttons-for-cocos2d/) if you are having trouble setting up your own buttons; it's very easy to use.